# Java Regular expression for checking validity of Variable name

Tags: java, regex

I have written below regular expression in java for checking the validity of a string, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

> ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]

Rule:

string can be alpha numeric and _ is the only allowed special chars

string can start with only alphabets a-z or A-Z

below java code returns false even though all conditions are met.

> ```
> "a1b".matches("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]")
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the beginning of line `^` anchor and place a  quantifier after your last character class `[]`

```
System.out.println("a1b".matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*")); // true
```

You could simply use..

```
System.out.println("a1b".matches("(?i)[a-z][a-z0-9_]*")); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quantifier `*` to make your regex match 0 or more times after first alphabet:

```
"a1b".matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
```

Or else use:

```
"a1b".matches("[a-zA-Z]\\w*");
```

**PS:** No need to use anchors `^` and `$` in `String#matches` since that is already implied.